# Changes on .xhtml files are not being deployed with Intellij Idea 2016.1 & Wildfly 9.0.2 final

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly-9

I have added following params to web.xml;

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

changed this line in standalone.xml as needed;

```
<jsp-config development="true"/>
```

In Intellij, under server configuration, I set "On frame deactivation" to "Update classes and resources". Under Settings > HotSwap, "Reload classes after compilation" is set to "Always". Also I'm pretty sure that the ".ear exploded" ones are being deployed in order to see any code changes. The problem is that I cannot see any web resource change even after restarting the server. Clearing browser cache also didn't help. Note that java class file changes are being correctly replaced by IDE, web resources aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you might want to try if you haven't already.

In project structure > modules, make sure that all of your resource directories are tagged properly as resources.

Under artifacts, make sure that your exploded artifact is including all the files you need.

What happens when you click the reload button on the debug or run window? Does it say "X resources reloaded"?

Comment: I marked webapp directories (that's a multi-module project) as resources but that didn't work. Clicking update says "Loaded classes are up to date. Nothing to reload."

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with deployment of .ear (.war worked fine). I had to check "Unpack nested archives" of the .ear in the File->Project Structure: 
[image]